# Mysql select query on Select query result

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table of products like:

```
id   name   price 
1    abc    200
2    def    300
3    ghi    400
4    jkl    500
5    mno    600
6    pqr    700
```

Now I have a query

```
"SELECT * FROM products where id >5"
```

now there is another query.

Now we have 4 products. Now we want to run query on the result of first query.

```
 "SELECT * From products where price > 400".
```

and this is dummy table and data

Comment: `SELECT * FROM products where id >5 and price > 400` combine it to one

Comment: use an AND, or, if it's more complicated than it looks like, a subquery.

Comment: Its a dummy data and dummy table. i want query on query result. in that scenorio and is great option. but i think i am not be able to explain my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your query could be more complicated than the example you show here, you can use a subquery:

```
select *
from 
    (
        select * from products where id > 5
    ) as a
where
    price > 400
```

Some rules:

- Subqueries must be enclosed in parenthesis.
- Subqueries *must* have an alias (the `as a` piece).

Hope this helps

Comment: let me implement ur solution.

Comment: Consider reading [the "Subquery Syntax" chapter in MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: @umair My guess is that downvotes are because you didn't checked the reference manual first. I recommend you read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).